# Express routes not hitting

Tags: node.js, express

my express app routes are not hitting, while testing in postman. There are two routes file under the routes directory exercises.js and users.js. Both routes file are being required in the server.js file.

// app routes code in server.js file

```
const exercisesRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/exercises', exercisesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

//exercises.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Exercise = require('../models/exercise.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    Exercise.find()
        .then(exercises => res.json(exercises))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const duration = Number(req.body.duration);
    const date = Date.parse(req.body.date);

    const newExercise = new Exercise({
        username,
        description,
        duration,
        date,
    });

    newExercise.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Exercise added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

//users.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    User.find()
        .then(users => res.json(users))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;

    const newUser = new User({ username });

    newUser.save()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('user added!')
            res.json('User added!');
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try on your routes files declaring express as:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express();
```

Then also on your endpoints the syntax I'm not too familiar, normally I would use:

```
router.get('/endpoint', async (req, res) => {
...
})
router.post('/endpoint2', async (req, res) => {
...
})
```